# How can I acces files with getenv() in c++ with using pipe in a bash?

Tags: c++, bash, pipe, mapper, getenv

I want to implement a function for MapReduce framework so my task is to create a mapper that concatenate text files.

Here is my bash script;

```
 for i in text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt
     do
         cat $i | ./myfunction
     done
```

And myfunction() will read the input files , line by line and the variable will be read with function getenv(). I tried with fopen(argv[1],"r") it gives me Segmentation fault and with popen() I get permission denied.

My code in C++:

```
 char *myenv;
 myenv = getenv("PWD");
 FILE *fileIN = popen(myenv , "r");
```

I don't know what exactly cat $i | ./myfunction does.Does it read "i" like an argument ? if yes, I get fileIN == NULL when I use fopen.

Comment: Can you try to elaborate on what your intention is, and maybe share the C++ code?

Comment: I hope that it seems better now

Comment: Piping will make data available on stdin. You should read a line from stdin as if you were trying to read user input.

Comment: @thatotherguy. Yes I thought so but why do I need getenv() then? Do you have an opinion for that ?

Comment: I don't know why you would need it. Nothing about the problem description suggests that `getenv` should be involved.

Comment: I guess you want to extract variable names and values by reading `*.txt` files. If you can provide some lines of them and describe what you want to do with them, we could be your help. I suppose `getenv` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a confusion here. `getenv` allows you to get environment variables, like `PWD`, which is just the path to your home directory.

Here, the pipe adds the output of the `echo` command to the args given to your executable. To get these args you should write your C++ code like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //do whatever you want with argv[1]
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: if you want to get the name of the file in your C++ code,  you should use `echo` instead of `cat`.

Comment: I am not allow to change anything in bash. So in this case I can not use argv. I read line from stdin but how can I get that which file are piping I have to get filename and index for every words